# Trigger event on first date select in ngx-bootstrap daterangepicker

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have date range picker `<bs-daterangepicker-inline [bsValue]='bsValue' (bsValueChange)="test()"></bs-daterangepicker-inline>`.

How can I trigger event when first date is selected? `bsValueChange` is only triggered when both dates are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the ngx-bootstrap daterangepicker doesn't support an event for selecting the first date. You can find a feature request for this here: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3348

In the comments you can also find a workaround similar to this one where you add the event listener to the daterangepicker yourself:

```js
const datepicker = this.document.querySelector('bs-daterangepicker-inline-container');
datepicker.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
    if (target.hasAttribute('bsdatepickerdaydecorator') && !target.classList.contains('disabled')) {
        const monthYearButtons: NodeListOf<HTMLButtonElement> = datepicker
            .querySelector('.bs-datepicker-head')
            .querySelectorAll('.current');

        const clickedDate = moment(
            `${target.innerText} ${monthYearButtons[0].innerText} ${monthYearButtons[1].innerText}`,
            'DD MMMM YYYY',
            'de' // locale of the daterangepicker
        );
    }

    // this is to find out if really the start date was selected
    // (dateRange contains the dates of the bsValueChange event)
    if (!clickedDate.isSame(this.dateRange[1]) || target.classList.contains('select-end')) {
        this.dateRange[0] = clickedDate.toDate();
        this.dateRange[1] = null;
    }
});
```